# How fully convolutional layer can work for segmentation task?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

I am reading the paper "Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation by Jonathan Long*, Evan Shelhamer*, and Trevor Darrell. CVPR 2015 and PAMI 2016"
I want to understand why it can work for semantic segmentation. Let look at the fcn-32s architecture, it includes two phases: feature extraction (conv1-1->pool5), and feature classification (fc6->score_fr). Comparison with a normal classification network, the main different is the second phase. The FCN-32s replaces the fully connected layer by fully convolution layers (1 x 1) in fc7 to retain the spatial map (as the caption in the figure 2 of the paper). Hence, I was confused something about this point:

1. If we replace the fully connected layer by fully convolution layer,
   how can it learn the weight as traditional classification
   architecture?
2. Why we can retain the spatial map (heatmap) by using fully convolution layer?

Thank you in advance.

Update: This is figure to show how convert from fully connected to fully convolution layers
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information/context, so readers don't have to google by themselves?  As it stands, in my opinion, only those that have ever read the paper && still remember would answer this question.

Comment: Thank javaLover. I updated it

Comment: Welcome.  I sometimes want to ask something like this.  On the topic,   the post looks like a big chunk of paragraph (less attractive).   Are you allowed to post paper link?  It also quotes about jargon(?) like "FCN-32s", "pool5" and "convolutional layer".  I don't know which one of them are common words in this area.  If some are not, provide what they do/mean might be a good idea. :)

Comment: @javaLover in [tag:caffe] [tag:deep-learning] using `pool5` and `FCN-32s` is okay. For people reasonably "into the stuff" these words actually mean something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the math, `"Convolution"` layer and `"InnerProduct"` (aka "fully connected") layer are basically quite similar: they perform a linear operation on their respective receptive fields. The only difference is that `"InnerProduct"` takes the entire input as its "receptive field" while `"Convolution"` layer only looks at `kernel_size` window in the input.

What happens if the input size is changed?
`"Convolution"` layer cannot care less, it simply outputs the feature map with spatial dimensions corresponding to the new input shape.
On the other hand, `"InnerProduct"` layer fails since the number of weights it has does not match the new size of the receptive field.

Replacing the top fully-connected layers in a model with `"Convolution"` layers allow for "sliding window" classification of the image: thus achieving coarse semantic segmentation - a labeling per-pixel rather than a label per image.

There is still a big issue of the scale gap between the input scale and the coarse scale of the output labels, but there are `"Deconvolution"` layers to bridge that gap.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I shown the shape of each layer: `fc6: (1, 4096, 16, 16), fc7: (1, 4096, 16, 16), score_fr: (1, 21, 16, 16)` where `fc6` uses kernel size `7`, `fc7` and `score_fr` use kernel size `1`. The `fc7` has `4096` feature maps, `score_fr` has `21` (number of class). As my understand, the 49 (7x7) input of the `fc6` are connected to a output in `fc7`. While, only 1 input in `fc7` is connected to 1 output in `score_fr`, because of kernel size: 1. Is it right? Besides, the weight of a convolution layer are randomly initialized,such as Gaussian kernel, so how does the weight learn ?

Comment: all weights of models are init to random, its the training process that tune the random weights into something useful @user8264

Comment: It means the last two convolutions are initialized randomly and then it will be fine tuning after next iterations. Or all convolution from 1 to 7?

Comment: @user8264 I'm not that familiar with the details of training `FCN-32s`.

Comment: Thank Shai. I think all weight in all convolution layers are tuned during training. Thank for valuable comment.